# Number Guessing Game Over Intervals

Tags: java, algorithm, range

I have just started my long path to becoming a better coder on CodeChef. People begin with the problems marked 'Easy' and I have done the same.

[The Problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/A3)

The problem statement defines the following -:

1. `n`, where `1 <= n <= 10^9`. This is the integer which Johnny is keeping secret.
2. `k`, where `1 <= k <= 10^5`. For each test case or instance of the game, Johnny provides exactly `k` hints to Alice.
3. A hint is of the form `op num Yes/No`, where -

   - `op` is an operator from `<`, `>`, `=`.
   - `num` is an integer, again satisfying `1 <= num <= 10^9`.
   - `Yes` or `No` are answers to the question: *Does the relation `n op num` hold?*
4. If the answer to the question is correct, Johnny has uttered a truth. Otherwise, he is lying.

Each hint is fed to the program and the program determines whether it is the truth or possibly a lie. My job is to find the minimum possible number of lies.

Now [CodeChef's Editorial answer](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/36507/a3-editorial) uses the concept of segment trees, which I cannot wrap my head around at all. I was wondering if there is an alternative data structure or method to solve this question, maybe a simpler one, considering it is in the 'Easy' category.

This is what I tried -:

```
class Solution //Represents a test case.
{
    HashSet<SolutionObj> set = new HashSet<SolutionObj>(); //To prevent duplicates.
    BigInteger max = new BigInteger("100000000"); //Max range.
    BigInteger min = new BigInteger("1"); //Min range.
    int lies = 0; //Lies counter.

    void addHint(String s)
    {
        String[] vals = s.split(" ");
        set.add(new SolutionObj(vals[0], vals[1], vals[2]));
    }

    void testHints()
    {
        for(SolutionObj obj : set)
        {
            //Given number is not in range. Lie.
            if(obj.bg.compareTo(min) == -1 || obj.bg.compareTo(max) == 1)
            {
                lies++;
                continue;
            }
            if(obj.yesno)
            {
                if(obj.operator.equals("<"))
                {
                    max = new BigInteger(obj.bg.toString()); //Change max value
                }
                else if(obj.operator.equals(">"))
                {
                    min = new BigInteger(obj.bg.toString()); //Change min value
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Still to think of this portion.
            }
        }
    }

}

class SolutionObj //Represents a single hint.
{
    String operator;
    BigInteger bg;
    boolean yesno;

    SolutionObj(String op, String integer, String yesno)
    {
        operator = op;
        bg = new BigInteger(integer);
        if(yesno.toLowerCase().equals("yes"))
            this.yesno = true;
        else
            this.yesno = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if(o instanceof SolutionObj)
        {
            SolutionObj s = (SolutionObj) o; //Make the cast
            if(this.yesno == s.yesno && this.bg.equals(s.bg)
                    && this.operator.equals(s.operator))
                return true;
        }
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return this.bg.intValue();
    }
}
```

Obviously this partial solution is incorrect, save for the range check that I have done before entering the `if(obj.yesno)` portion. I was thinking of updating the range according to the hints provided, but that approach has not borne fruit. How should I be approaching this problem, apart from using segment trees?

Comment: Why don't you try to learn about segment tree? Hardly to go any further without understanding basic concepts like segment tree, binary index tree ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following approach, which may be easier to understand. Picture the 1d axis of integers, and place on it the k hints. Every hint can be regarded as '(' or ')' or '=' (greater than, less than or equal, respectively).

Example:

```
-----(---)-------(--=-----)-----------)
```

Now, the true value is somewhere on one of the 40 values of this axis, but actually only 8 segments are interesting to check, since anywhere inside a segment the number of true/false hints remains the same. 
That means you can scan the hints according to their ordering on the axis, and maintain a counter of the true hints at that point.

In the example above it goes like this:

```
segment         counter
-----------------------
-----(             3
---                4
)-------(          3
--                 4
=                  5 <---maximum
-----              4
)-----------       3
)                  2
```

This algorithm only requires to sort the k hints and then scan them. It's near linear in k (O(k*log k), with no dependance on n), therefore it should have a reasonable running time.

**Notes:**

1) In practice the hints may have non-distinct positions, so you'll have to handle all hints of the same type on the same position together.

2)  If you need to return the minimum set of lies, then you should maintain a set rather than a counter. That shouldn't have an effect on the time complexity if you use a hash set.

Comment: For a point in the axis, the number of lies equals to the number of '(' and '=' after this point and number of ')' and '=' before this point, am I correct? two scans should be taken for this counting scheme :)

Comment: @PhamTrung: Yes, you'll need one scan to determine the initial value of the counter, and then a second scan to track the value of the counter as you jump between the segments. The scans are linear in k.

Comment: Very nice, I think it is better than what I have in mind, when you only need to keep track of one number:)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the number of lies if the target number = 1 (store this in a variable `lies`).

Let `target` = 1.

Sort and group the statements by their respective values.

Iterate through the statements.

- Update `target` to the current statement group's value. Update `lies` according to how many of those statements would become either true or false.
- Then update `target` to that value + 1 (Why do this? Consider when you have `> 5` and `< 7` - `6` may be the best value) and update `lies` appropriately (skip this step if the next statement group's value is this value).

Return the minimum value for `lies`.

**Running time:**

`O(k)` for the initial calculation.

`O(k log k)` for the sort.

`O(k)` for the iteration.

`O(k log k)` total.

Answer (score 0):

My idea for this problem is similar to how Eyal Schneider view it. Denoting '>' as greater, '<' as less than and '=' as equals, we can sort all the 'hints' by their `num` and scan through all the interesting points one by one.

For each point, we keep in all the number of '<' and '=' from 0 to that point (in one array called `int[]lessAndEqual`), number of '>' and '=' from that point onward (in one array called `int[]greaterAndEqual`). We can easily see that the number of lies in a particular point `i` is equal to

```
lessAndEqual[i] + greaterAndEqual[i + 1]
```

We can easily fill the `lessAndEqual` and `greaterAndEqual` arrays by two scan in O(n) and sort all the hints in O(nlogn), which result the time complexity is O(nlogn)

Note: special treatment should be taken for the case when the `num` in hint is equals. Also notice that the range for num is 10^9, which require us to have some forms of point compression to fit the array into the memory